Multiple conditions in array for comparison?
I am trying to check conditions inside foreach for a dynamic array.
My Array:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => target_id
            [operator] => Equals
            [value] => 13
            [operation] => OR
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => target_id
            [operator] => Equals
            [value] => 14
            [operation] => OR
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => target_id
            [operator] => Equals
            [value] => 15
            [operation] => OR
        )
)

Say I have a variable:
$target_id = 14;

I want to check this way
$override = false;

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value["type"] == "target_id" && $value["operator"] == "Equals"){
        if($target_id == $value["value"]){
            $override = true;
        }
    }
}

If I generate a filter string, it would look like: 13 == 14 OR 14 == 14 OR 14 == 15
So my logic would be if(13 == 14 OR 14 == 14 OR 14 == 15)
I am not sure how to add the operation condition inside foreach. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

I don't really understand the jump from that perfectly fine PHP code to "13 == 14 OR 14 == 14 OR 14 == 15", or what exactly the question is. Please clarify.

hard to tell - which array keys are dynamic? what is your goal? You could pluck your types in a single array with array_column($array, 'type') and check if the $target_id is in that array.
eval() may be helpful in your case. you would need to change "equals" to "=="

It doesn't make sense for the OR or AND operator to be in each condition -- if you have a mixture of AND and OR, how do you know which of the other conditions should be combined with that operator. You should use a hierarchical structure like ['operator' => 'OR/AND', 'children' = [['operator' => 'equals', 'field' => 'type_id', 'value' => 13], ['operator' => 'equals', 'field' => 'type_id', 'value' => 14]]]

I guess I was not able to make myself clear on this. All I meant was that I wanted to generate a filter string inside foreach. So I had this after the foreach $filterstring = "14 == 12 OR 15 == 15 OR 12 == 11". I made this work using eval(). Thank you so much @ChristianWagner for your help. Again I am sorry if I was not able to make myself very clear on this.
